# How to return result set with incremented rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server ROW_NUMBER() on SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081753/sql-server-row-number-on-sql-server-2000)

How do I return a row and an ascending counter as a result set?

The function Row_number() is not known in MS SQL 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable table with an identity column and insert the results into it:

```
DECLARE TABLE @MYTABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    VALUES......
)
INSERT INTO @MYTABLE
SELECT MYVALUES.....

SELECT * FROM @MYTABLE
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was trying to avoid a middle man table.  But your answer is what I was using.  I guess I'll go with that.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Phillip: Sorry, SQL 2000 just don't play nice.  We use SQL 2005 and set its compat mode to 2000... eh.

Comment: Unfortunately, this **is not** guaranteed to give consective numbers. See demo here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4219201/27535 and then see alternatives here http://stackoverflow.com/q/4081753/27535

Comment: @gbn: Thanks for pointing that out.  The problem is different than what the question asks though.  If he's using that just for displaying purposes, then there isn't a problem.  But if he's using it for paging, then this wouldn't work well at all.

Comment: Agree, it's still useful depending on how OP wants to use it. Just wanted to add this warning