# Getting a recordID in my SQL select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, select

I have a simple stored procedure that returns records:

```
Select empID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName from EMPLOYEES
```

The returned result is:

```
    EmpID         EmpFirstName       EmpLastName  
    -----         ------------       -----------  
   30152          John               Smith  
   30114          Tom                Jones  
   56332          Steve              Williams  
   85442          Paul               Johnson
```

What I need is:

```
 RecID       EmpID         EmpFirstName       EmpLastName  
 -----       -----         ------------       -----------  
 1      30152          John               Smith  
 2      30114          Tom                Jones  
 3      56332          Steve              Williams  
 4      85442          Paul               Johnson
```

How can I get the recordID column?

Thanks

Comment: `Select RecID, empID, EmpFirstName, EmpLastName from EMPLOYEES` ? What is the structure of your DB?

Comment: What is determining the order for the assignment of RecID? Sorted by EmpID, 30114 will have RecID = 1. Does that matter?

Comment: There's a difference between a record 'ID' (i.e., some value stored in your database that positively identifies a record), and a line number (which is just an arbitrary number that will not necessarily identify the same row if you run the query again.)  Which is it that you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably want to use [Row_Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
Select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY empID) AS RecId, 
       empID, 
       EmpFirstName, 
       EmpLastName 
from EMPLOYEES
```

unless there is actually a `RecId` column in `EMPLOYEES` in which case it would just be this:

```
Select RecId, 
       empID, 
       EmpFirstName, 
       EmpLastName 
from EMPLOYEES
```

Comment: ok, that works. Lets say if there was no empID, what would I use as "Order By" ?

Comment: You can use any other column in there.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using at least SQL Server 2005, [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) is what you need.

Example:

```
Select
    row_number() over (order by empID) as RecID,
    empID, 
    EmpFirstName, 
    EmpLastName
from 
    EMPLOYEES
```

If you're using SQL Server 2000 or older, it's unfortunately not that easy.
SQL Server 2000 doesn't support `ROW_NUMBER`, but there are some [workarounds](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/13daeb85-da43-4166-b188-595a4a5d5282/) to achieve something similar.
[All of them seem to have some drawbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081753/sql-server-row-number-on-sql-server-2000/4081797#4081797), though.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY empID) as RowId, 
    empID, 
    EmpFirstName, 
    EmpLastName 
FROM EMPLOYEES
```

[More details on ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)