# How to fill `[Order]` column by order number in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, sql-order-by

How to fill `[Order]` column by order number in SQL Server 2000?

For example, I have a SQL:

```
select Id, Tilte 
from Tbl 
order by Date
```

I need to write order number from this query to column `[Order]` of `Tbl` table.

How to do this?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Id, Title, [Order] 
   , OrderNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date)
   FROM Tbl 
)
UPDATE CTE SET [Order] = CTE.OrderNumber;
```

Here's a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8831d/2/0

Comment: Thanks! But is possible more simple syntax there?

Comment: @Altaveron: This is probably the simplest way to do

Comment: @Altaveron: Once you're familiar with a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) it's very easy and the `ROW_NUMBER` is self-explanatory, isn't it?

Comment: Why not just "SELECT [Order] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) FROM Tbl"? It works too. Is it correct?

Comment: @Altaveron: I thought you wanted to update that value in the table(_"fill column"_). Otherwise you can also use it without a cte. Apart from that, a cte is just an easy way to avoid many sub queries and to keep the sql clean and readable.

Comment: Yes, but the code above is "[Order] = ROW_NUMBER()". The data on the column was updated correctly. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: SQL Server 2000 returns: 'ROW_NUMBER' is not a recognized function name :(

Comment: `ROW_Number` (and `Common Table Expressions`) were new in SQL-Server 2005. That's why it's important to tag the approriate version in the first place. All the more when you use such an old version. You would need a temporary table to simulate it. Have [a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081753/sql-server-row-number-on-sql-server-2000).

Comment: I think temp table is not mandatory. But we have to use a hard SQL.