# Modify SQL query with Row_Number() and partition functions for SQL Server 2000

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2000, row-number

This is my current SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Machine_ID] ORDER BY Version DESC) AS ROW, 
   MachineList.*
FROM  
   MachineList
```

Basically, I want to get distinct machine information. If several machines have the same `ID`, then choose the one with latest version.

However, SQL Server 2000 does not support the `ROW_Number` function. Is there any alternative for the SQL above?

P.S. most solutions I found on line are using temp table. But I could not use temp table because this query will be used in SSIS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server ROW\_NUMBER() on SQL Server 2000?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081753/sql-server-row-number-on-sql-server-2000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select m.*
 from machinelist as m
        inner join (
               select
                     t.machine_id, max(t.version) as version
               from machinelist as t
               group by t.machine_id
        ) as mm on
              mm.machine_id = m.machine_id and mm.version = m.version
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use an inline temp table to compute highest version for each machineID. Presumably the SSIS restriction on temp tables applies to # tables and not inline temp tables

```
SELECT  M.*
FROM  MachineList M inner join
(select Machine_ID, max(Version) from MachineList 
group by Machine_ID ) Z on M.Machine_id = Z.Machine_id 
and M.Version = Z.Version
```